# conditional useEffect react

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

i have a useEffect function to get data from localstorage and store it to state

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

const getTempCart = () => {
    const cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartProduct"));
    setData(cart);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getTempCart()
  }, [])
```

then i have useEffect to copy state to new localstorage

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("finalCart", JSON.stringify(data))) //copy data state to localstorage by key 'finalCart'
  }, [data]);
```

my question is how to prevent second useEffect run and redirect to homepage when `data === null`. Try to make some conditional

```js
useEffect(() => {
if (data === null) {
window.location.replace('/')
  } else {
localStorage.setItem("finalCart", JSON.stringify(data))}
}, [data])
```

but its not working at all

Comment: _my question is how to prevent second useEffect run and redirect to homepage when `data === null`_ - `if` statement inside the `useEffect` hook is doing exactly what you don't want

Comment: if you want to prevent second useEffect run and redirect to homepage when data === null then shouldn't you be doing  data !== null ??

Comment: @MohammadFaisal nah, that is the problem and now its working flawlessly..thank you

Comment: @Yousaf oh i just found out about it